# How to order a set of object in a view

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My code currently lists all `domains` in a `server` using:

```
{% for domain in server.domain_set.all %}
```

I want to order the domains in the view by their url. Something like:

```
{% for domain in server.domain_set.all().order_by('url') %}
```

But I get an exception `"could not parse the remainder"`. How can I order the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [dictsort](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort) filter:

> Takes a list of dictionaries and returns that list sorted by the key
>   given in the argument.

```
{% for domain in server.domain_set.all|dictsort:'url' %}
```

Also see:

- [Sorting related items in a Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540032/sorting-related-items-in-a-django-template)
- [order_by template filter](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/741/)

Answer (score 4):

The "could not parse the remainder" errors is because you're including Python code in your django template. Django doesn't allow that.

You could add a method on the model:

```
def sorted_domains(self):
    return self.domain_set.all().order_by('url')
```

And then call it like this:

```
{% for domain in server.sorted_domains %}
```

An alternative is to set the default sort order on your `Domain` model with a [Meta attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid agreed, I really like this more than doing this in the template. Much cleaner.