# Sorting related items in descending order in django template

Tags: html, django, sorting, templates

I want to sorting items from database in descending order in template page

```
{% for n in article.comment_set.all %}
  {{ n.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Model Example:**

```
class comment(models.Model):
   text = models.TextField(verbose_name="Add Comment")
   art = models.ForeignKey(article, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting related items in a Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540032/sorting-related-items-in-a-django-template)

Comment: you want to sort items but what is key? which parameter you want to use for sorting the items?

Comment: I already do this but not working.

Comment: i want to sorting by id

Answer (score 0):

In Your view using this to sort in Descending order

```
Comm = comment.objects.order_by('-id')
```