# Sort by field value in Django 2.0

Tags: django, django-models

This question is like [django sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540032/sorting-related-items-in-a-django-template) but I can't make any of the solutions work.

I have the following model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    body = models.TextField()
    url = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    votes_total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    hunter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def summary(self):
        return self.body[:50]

    def pub_date_pretty(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I would like to sort by votes_total so that when I loop through the database results are ordered by votes_total.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% for product in products.all %}
<div class="row pt-3">
  <div class="col-2" onclick="window.location='{% url 'detail' product.id %}';" style="cursor:pointer">
    <img src="{{ product.icon.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6" onclick="window.location='{% url 'detail' product.id %}';" style="cursor:pointer">
    <h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ product.summary }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" onclick="window.location='{% url 'detail' product.id %}';" style="cursor:pointer">
    <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('upvote{{ product.id }}').submit()}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><span class="oi oi-caret-top"></span> Upvote {{ product.votes_total }}</button></a>
  </div>
</div>

<form id="upvote{{ product.id }}" method="POST" action="{% url 'upvote' product.id %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden">
</form>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

How do I sort my results?

Comment: What `view` do you use to render the response? You better prepare this ordered queryset in a view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are basically two ways you can do this:

1. define the ordering in a *view*; or
2. define a *default* ordering (an ordering that can be overridden with another ordering) in the *model*.

The last option is typically used if the model has a sensical (inherent) ordering (for example it is very logical to order a queryset in a certain way, and only occasionally in another way).

## Sorting in a *view*

We can sort a queryset, by using the [**`.order_by(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) function of a queryset. The function takes an arbitrary number of parameters: strings that specify the column names. In case a column name is prefixed with a minus (`-`) it means we sort in descending order.

For example we can define a view:

```
def some_view(request):
    my_products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-votes_total')
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'my_products': my_products})
```

then we can use this `'my_products'` variable, and iterate over it:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% for product in my_products %}
<div class="row pt-3">
  <div class="col-2" onclick="window.location='{% url 'detail' product.id %}';" style="cursor:pointer">
    <img src="{{ product.icon.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6" onclick="window.location='{% url 'detail' product.id %}';" style="cursor:pointer">
    <h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ product.summary }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" onclick="window.location='{% url 'detail' product.id %}';" style="cursor:pointer">
    <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('upvote{{ product.id }}').submit()}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><span class="oi oi-caret-top"></span> Upvote {{ product.votes_total }}</button></a>
  </div>
</div>

<form id="upvote{{ product.id }}" method="POST" action="{% url 'upvote' product.id %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden">
</form>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

## Define an ordering on a *model*

In case a certain ordering is quite logical from a model perspective, we can also encapsulate the ordering in the model itself. We specify this wth the `ordering` attribute of the `Meta` class of the attribute. In case we want for example to order `Product.objects.all()` by default by the number of votes in *descending* order, we can write:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    body = models.TextField()
    url = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    votes_total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    hunter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-votes_total']
```

So now we can still access `Product.objects.all` in the template, and the items will be sorted automatically.

Note however that we can define only one such ordering per model, and thus making a certain decision, can not be specified based on a particular view. In case you want to "override" the ordering, you need to user `order_by` on the queryset.

Answer (score 3):

You should sort the `queryset` in your view and pass it to the template. For sorting it in ascending order

```
return render(request, template_name,{
    'products': Product.objects.all().order_by('votes_total')
})
```

For sorting in descending order:

```
return render(request, template_name,{
    'products': Product.objects.all().order_by('-votes_total')
})
```

You should use `products` (not products.all) in your template.