# OOP: getter/setter methods

Tags: python, oop

So I've read that you're supposed to access object attributes through getter/setter methods like `object.get_this()` or `object.set_that(value)`. Does this code hold for methods that are also defined within the class? Or they are only meant to be used with object instances. For instance, is it idiomatic to do it this way,

```
class test:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
    def get_value(self):
        return self.value
    def method(self):
        return some_operation(self.value)
```

with `get_value()` defined for accessing `value` for an object instance, or should `get_value()` also be used within class methods?

```
class test:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
    def get_value(self):
        return self.value
    def method(self):
        return some_operation(self.get_value())
```

Comment: Check for the `property` built-in function: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

Comment: I don't know where you've read this, but I'll bet it wasn't in any Python context. In Python, the opposite is true.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In python [**do not use** getter/setter methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554546/when-and-how-to-use-the-builtin-function-property-in-python).  Instead just access the attribute itself, or, if you need code to be run every time the attribute is accessed or set, use [properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: +1 Additional reason for doing that: [Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't access attributes of an object in methods of said object by a different way than what I would expect methods from other objects to access them. Why? I'm not sure, it just seems very weird.

Python makes this really easy if you use the [properties decorator](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) which eliminates the need for getters/setters named like "get_foo" / "set_foo".