# Accessor & Mutator methods (Python)

Tags: python, mutators

I am trying to figure out encapsulation in Python.  I was doing a simple little test in shell to see how something worked and it doesn't work like I was expecting.  And I can't get it to work.  Here's my code:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, carMake, yrMod):
        self.__make = carMake
        self.__yearModel = yrMod
        self.__speed = 0

    #Mutator Methods
    def set_make(self, make):
        self.__make = carMake

    def set_model(self, yrMod):
        self.__yearModel = yrMod

    #def set_speed(self, speed):
        #self.__speed = speed

    #Accessor Methods
    def get_make(self):
        return self.__make

    def get_yearModel(self):
        return self.__yearModel

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed

myCar=Car('Ford', 1968)
myCar2=Car('Nissan', 2012)
myCar.get_make()
'Ford'
myCar.set_make=('Porche')
myCar.get_make()
'Ford'
```

Why doesn't myCar.set_make change Ford into Porche?  Thank you.

Comment: What's with all these underscores in your instance attributes, e.g. `self.__speed`?  And why are you making all these methods anyhow?  What advantage do you think `myCar.set_make("Porsche")/myCar.get_make()` will offer over `myCar.make = 'Porsche'` and `myCar.make`?

Comment: There is never a reason to expose an API like this. There is sometimes a reason to have getter/setter methods, but they should be hidden using the built-in `property`. And since that makes them like normal attributes from the client code's perspective, you should just use those (rather than trivial getters/setters) until you need logic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `myCar.set_make=('Porche')`, you are setting this member the Car class as the `'Porche'` string, but you are not calling the method.

Just remove the `=` to solve it:

```
myCar.set_make('Porche')
myCar.get_make() # Porche
```

Besides, as @DSM points out, there is an error in the argument of `set_make`:

```
def set_make(self, make):
    self.__make = make # carMake is not defined!
```

However, [this use of getters and setters in Python is strongly discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554546/when-and-how-to-use-the-builtin-function-property-in-python#1555169). If you need something similar for any reason, consider using [properties](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: There's also a bug in `set_make` (`carMake` instead of `make`) so it won't quite work yet, but you're right about the main problem.

Comment: Thank you for that, but for some reason I get an error message:

Comment: This was my first time using this resource, I just started an intro to programming class, so thank you for your patience!

Answer (score -1):

```
new_car = Car(...)
new_car2 = Car(...)

new_car._make = 'Ford'
new_car2.make = 'Jetta'

print new_car._make
print new_car2.make
```

Comment: And what value does this answer add to the question? Since you took the time to post this as an answer to a year old question I'm curious.