# My function returns None, Python 3

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I am not too sure why this returns None, it worked perfectly before I tried putting it into a function. It is supposed to return a list of words that are between 6 and 9 characters long.

```
def level_list(minn, maxx):
    for words in word_list:
        if len(words) >= minn and len(words) <= maxx:
            return level_words.append(words)

print(level_list(6, 9))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.append` is a mutator method, meaning that unlike string methods which return the modified version of the string, this directly changes the list and returns `None`.

---

More about:

[List mutability](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/)

[Mutator methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867664/accessor-mutator-methods-python)

[More mutator methods](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php)