# Dynamically setting attribute as function in Python class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating a simple game that contains classes called 'Player' and 'Strategy'. I want to assign a Strategy instance to the Player instance when the Player is created.

```
class Player(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.Strategy = None

    def Decision(self, InputA, InputB):

        Result = self.Strategy(InputA, InputB)
        return Result

    def SetStrategy(self):
        # Sets a strategy instance to the Player instance


class Strategy(object):

    def Strategy1(self, InputA, InputB):
        return InputA * InputB

    def Strategy2(self, InputA, InputB):
        return (InputA - InputB) / 2

    def Strategy3(self, InputA, InputB):
        return 0
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

in[0] Player1 = Player()

in[1] Player2 = Player()

in[2]: Player1.SetStrategy('Strategy1')

in[3]: Player2.SetStrategy('Strategy3')

in[4]: Player1.Decision(2,5)

out[0]: 10

in[5]: Player2.Decision(3,6)

out[1]: 0

Searching here and via google shows me ways of doing it with monkey patching but the approach looks a little inelegant (and although I'm a beginner I think there's a better way to do it) - is there a way to do this with inheritance that I'm not seeing?

Comment: The Strategy class contain functions which don't use a class instance nor the class, why don't you add the @staticmethod decorator to these functions?

Answer (score 1):

```
def strategy1(inputA, inputB):                  # 2
    return inputA * inputB

def strategy2(inputA, inputB):
    return (inputA - inputB) / 2

def strategy3(inputA, inputB):
    return 0

strategy = {
    'mul': strategy1,
    'diff': strategy2,
    'zero': strategy3
}

class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, strategy_name='mul'):      # 1
        self.strategy_name = strategy_name        # 5

    def decision(self, inputA, inputB):           # 4
        result = strategy[self.strategy_name](inputA, inputB)
        return result

player1 = Player()
player2 = Player()
player1.strategy_name = 'mul'                     # 3
player2.strategy_name = 'zero'
print(player1.decision(2, 5))
# 10

print(player2.decision(3, 6))
# 0
```

---

1. Every player has a strategy, so don't allow instantiation of Player 
   without assigning some strategy. You could use a default strategy
   (as    shown below), or make `strategy` a mandatory argument.
2. The strategies could be plain functions; I don't see a reason to
   bundle them as methods of a Strategy class. Always keep code as
   simple as possible; [don't use a class when a function would suffice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0#t=9m26s);
   use a class when it provides some feature (such as inheritance) which
   makes the class-based solution simpler.
3. In Python there is [no need for getters/setters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1555169/190597) like `setStrategy`.
   You can use plain attributes for simple values, and properties to
   implement more complicated behavior. Attributes and properties use
   the same syntax, so you can switch from one to the other without
   having to change have the class is used.
4. There is a convention (recommended in PEP8) that classes be named in
   CamelCase, and instances, functions and variables in lowercase. The
   convention is used ubiquitously, and following it will help other
   understand your code more easily.
5. To make it easy to store the strategy in a database, you could store
   the `strategy_name` in the database, and use a lookup dict (such as
   `strategy`) to associate the name with the actual function.

Comment: `In Python there is no need for getters/setters like setStrategy` --> functions are first-class citizens in python!

Comment: I included the 'SetStrategy' method as I wasn't sure how to reference the name of the strategy (i.e. if the Players were stored in a database, their strategy would be stored as a string and I assume that some further code will be required to assign a function based on it's name as a string?). Valid point about making the strategies functions though - trying to make it too complicated :)