# How does Python return multiple values from a function?

Tags: python, function, return

I have written the following code:

```
class FigureOut:
   def setName(self, name):
      fullname = name.split()
      self.first_name = fullname[0]
      self.last_name = fullname[1]

   def getName(self):
      return self.first_name, self.last_name

f = FigureOut()
f.setName("Allen Solly")
name = f.getName()
print (name)
```

I get the following **Output:**

```
('Allen', 'Solly')
```

Whenever multiple values are returned from a function in python, does it always convert the multiple values to a **list of multiple values** and then returns it from the function?

*Is the whole process same as converting the multiple values to a `list` explicitly and then returning the list, for example in Java, as one can return only one object from a function in Java?*

Comment: If you return two items from a function, then you are returning a tuple of length two, because that is how returning multiple items works. It's not a list.

Comment: @khelwood: So, is it a special feature in python?? One which is not present in languages like JAVA, C++ ..??

Comment: It is a feature not present in languages that do not support returning multiple values.

Comment: @khelwood: So, actually it does not return multiple values but a **tuple** of multiple values. Am I right??

Comment: I would say that tuples are the mechanism by which Python allows you to return multiple values.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since the return statement in `getName` specifies *multiple elements*:

```
def getName(self):
   return self.first_name, self.last_name
```

Python will return a container object that basically contains them.

In this case, returning a *comma separated* set of elements creates *a tuple*. Multiple values *can only be returned inside containers*.

Let's use a simpler function that returns multiple values:

```
def foo(a, b):
    return a, b
```

You can look at the byte code generated by using [`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis), a disassembler for Python bytecode. For comma separated values w/o any brackets, it looks like this:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo(a, b):
...     return a,b        
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              2
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see the values are first loaded on the internal stack with `LOAD_FAST` and then a [`BUILD_TUPLE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_TUPLE) (grabbing the previous `2` elements placed on the stack) is generated. Python knows to create a tuple due to the commas being present.

You could alternatively specify another return type, for example a list, by using `[]`. For this case, a [`BUILD_LIST`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_LIST) is going to be issued following the same semantics as it's tuple equivalent:

```
>>> def foo_list(a, b):
...     return [a, b]
>>> dis.dis(foo_list)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              6 BUILD_LIST               2
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

The type of object returned really depends on the presence of brackets (for tuples `()` can be omitted if there's at least one comma). `[]` creates lists and `{}` sets. Dictionaries need `key:val` pairs.

To summarize, *one actual object is returned*. If that object is of a container type, it can contain multiple values giving the impression of multiple results returned. The usual method then is to unpack them directly:

```
>>> first_name, last_name = f.getName()
>>> print (first_name, last_name)
```

---

As an aside to all this, your Java ways are leaking into Python :-)

Don't use getters when writing classes in Python, use `properties`. Properties are the idiomatic way to manage attributes, for more on these, see a nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554546/when-and-how-to-use-the-builtin-function-property-in-python).

Comment: Moreover, `getThis` and `setThat` are obsolete hold-overs from the Java bean days.  I would like to see an end to this paradigm once and for all.  `object.foo()` implies a "get" and `object.foo(value)` already implies a set.

Answer (score 23):

From [Python Cookbook v.30](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/ch07s04.html)

```
def myfun():
    return 1, 2, 3
```

```
a, b, c = myfun()
```

> **Although it looks like `myfun()` returns multiple values, a `tuple` is actually being created.** It looks a bit peculiar, but it’s actually the comma that forms a tuple, not the parentheses

So yes, what's going on in Python is an internal transformation from multiple comma separated values to a tuple and vice-versa.

Though there's no equivalent in [java](/questions/tagged/java) you can easily create this behaviour using `array`'s or some `Collection`s like `List`s:

```
private static int[] sumAndRest(int x, int y) {
    int[] toReturn = new int[2];

    toReturn[0] = x + y;
    toReturn[1] = x - y;

    return toReturn;

}
```

Executed in this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] results = sumAndRest(10, 5);

    int sum  = results[0];
    int rest = results[1];

    System.out.println("sum = " + sum + "\nrest = " + rest);

}
```

result:

```
sum = 15
rest = 5
```

Answer (score 6):

Here It is actually returning `tuple`.

If you execute this code in Python 3:

```
def get():
    a = 3
    b = 5
    return a,b
number = get()
print(type(number))
print(number)
```

**Output :**

```
<class 'tuple'>
(3, 5)
```

But if you change the code line `return [a,b]` instead of `return a,b` and execute :

```
def get():
    a = 3
    b = 5
    return [a,b]
number = get()
print(type(number))
print(number)
```

**Output :**

```
<class 'list'>
[3, 5]
```

It is only returning single object which contains multiple values.

There is another alternative to `return` statement for returning multiple values, use `yield`( to check in details see this [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python))

**Sample Example :**

```
def get():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i
number = get()
print(type(number))
print(number)
for i in number:
    print(i)
```

**Output :**

```
<class 'generator'>
<generator object get at 0x7fbe5a1698b8>
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 3):

Python functions always return a unique value. The comma operator is the constructor of tuples so `self.first_name, self.last_name` evaluates to a tuple and that tuple is the actual value the function is returning.

Answer (score 2):

> Whenever multiple values are returned from a function in python, does it always convert the multiple values to a **list** of multiple values and then returns it from the function??

I'm just adding a name and print the result that returns from the function.
the type of result is '**tuple**'.

```
  class FigureOut:
   first_name = None
   last_name = None
   def setName(self, name):
      fullname = name.split()
      self.first_name = fullname[0]
      self.last_name = fullname[1]
      self.special_name = fullname[2]
   def getName(self):
      return self.first_name, self.last_name, self.special_name

f = FigureOut()
f.setName("Allen Solly Jun")
name = f.getName()
print type(name)
```

I don't know whether you have heard about '**first class function**'. Python is the language that has '[first class function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)'

I hope my answer could help you.
Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

mentioned also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python), you can use this:

```
import collections
Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
p = Point(1, y=2)
>>> p.x, p.y
1 2
>>> p[0], p[1]
1 2
```