# How is this "operation" called in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand how this bit works:

```
Var_1, Var_2, Result =  some_function()
```

**the script:**

```
def some_function():
    return True, False, {"Some": "Dictionary"}

def main():
    Var_1, Var_2, Result =  some_function()
    if not Var_1:
        do something
    else:
        do something_else(Var_2, Result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For me the difficult to grasp is the bit of doing inception and provide(return) values which will be used in the main function and in the same trigger the `some_function()` from within the `main()` function.

Since I'm new to advanced concepts in python, I found it really interesting. How this "operation" is called so I can read a bit more about how it works. i.e. returning some values in line order separated by `,` and interpreting them based on the position in line(for the lack of better description).

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345995/how-does-python-return-multiple-values-from-a-function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's returning a [*tuple*](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/tuples.html). A tuple in Python is similar to a list, but it's immutable: you can't add, remove or replace items.

Often, tuples are constructed with the syntax `(a, b, c)`, but the parentheses are optional in many cases, so `a, b, c` is also valid.

On the receiving end, [*tuple unpacking*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples#Packing_and_Unpacking) is used to get the individual elements of the tuple, and assign them to separate variables.

Comment: One nice usage: you can use the power of tuple unpacking to switch values: `a, b = b, a`.

Answer (score 3):

What is happening here is in fact not that several values are returned. Instead, a single tuple is returned, and this is then unpacked using something called [tuple unpacking](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples#Packing_and_Unpacking).

The code is equivalent to

```
tmp_tuple = some_function()  # return tuple
Var_1, Var_2, Result = tmp_tuple  # unpack tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

`some_function()` returns [a tuple](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html) `(True, False, {"Some": "Dictionary"})`.

Tuples are very useful for grouping related data, for example something like `('John Smith', 1960, 'England', 'London', 'Newham')` might be a better way to store information about a person then creating 5 separate variables.

When `Var_1, Var_2, Result = tmp_tuple` is called this tuple is [unpacked](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples#Packing_and_Unpacking):

```
 (Var_1, Var_2, Result) = (True, False, {"Some": "Dictionary"})
```

And hence:

```
Var_1 = True
Var_2 = False
Result = {"Some": "Dictionary"}
```

Answer (score 0):

[The docs say:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists)

```
Except when part of a list or set display, an expression list containing at least one comma yields a tuple
```

This means `return x,y` will return a single object - a tuple and the rest is just **unpacking** it to the separate values.

So i would say those are two operation: tuple creation in return statement and tuple unpacking in main.