# Returning more than one output in C extensions?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, cpython

Python allows to return more than one result using commas as separating value.

When developing a CPython extension written in C language, is it possible to obtain the same result? How?

I'm developing a CPython extension that replaces an existing Python code to do some tests on performance and I will prefer to have the same interface to not change the existing code base.

I'm using Python 3.6.

Comment: If you separate multiple values, python actually returns a single value (namely a Tuple) which contains the values you've provided. So you just need to handle the Tuple data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create a tuple with [`PyTuple_New`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_New), populate it and return it. The callee will be able to unpack the result as usual.

Python returns multiple values by using containers. A single object is returned that is unpacked. Comma separated means tuple; in square brackets, on the other hand, a list is created. See [*How does Python return multiple values from a function*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345995/how-does-python-return-multiple-values-from-a-function/39346109#39346109) for more on this.

If you'd like an example of how one might do this in `C` you can take a look at [the implementation of `str.partition`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Objects/stringlib/partition.h#L8) or [`array.buffer_info`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/56935a53b11b9a70f3e13e460777ec81a5b9195e/Modules/arraymodule.c#L1283) (or any tuple returning built-in method).