# What is this grammar?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

`(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()`

This is tensorflow example, but I can't understand what it means
I know purpose of x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test but I want to know how those are assigned. What kind of mechanism it is.
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Python return multiple values from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345995/how-does-python-return-multiple-values-from-a-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called tuple or iterable unpacking. `mnist.load_data()` must return a sequence of two two-tuples:

```
>>> (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = [(1,2),(3,4)]
>>> x_train
1
>>> y_train
2
>>> x_test
3
>>> y_test
4
```

It can be used to unpack nested sequences:

```
>>> a,b,c = 1,2,3      # a=1,b=2,c=3
>>> (a,b),c = (1,2),3  # same
```

Use `*` to operate on varying sizes of sequences:

```
>>> a,*b = 1,2,3,4,5
>>> a
1
>>> b
[2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> a,*b,c = 1,2,3,4,5
>>> a
1
>>> b
[2, 3, 4]
>>> c
5
```

References::

- [Python Docs - Assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)
- [PEP 3132 - Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of the `mnist.load_data()`, you can see that the return is:

```
Returns
Tuple of Numpy arrays: (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test).
```

This means it returns two tuples, one for x and one for y.

In general, if a function returns two values, like:

```
def fun():
    return a,b
```

You can get the results like this:
x,y = fun()

Here, the function mnist_load() is of the form:

```
def mnist_load():
    return (x_train,y_train), (x_test,y_test)
```

As others have said, this is called tuple unpacking.