# Property in Python with @property.getter

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, python-2.x

I have an intresting behaviour for the following code:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.abc = 10

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self.abc

    @age.getter
    def age(self):
        return self.abc + 10

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        self.abc = value

obj = MyClass()
print(obj.age)
obj.age = 12
print(obj.age)
obj.age = 11
print(obj.age)
```

And I have the following result:

```
20
12
11
```

Can somebody explain this behaviour ?

Comment: Are you sure you're on Python 3? This looks like Python 2 behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On old style classes (which yours is if you're executing on Python `2`) the assignment `obj.age = 11` will 'override' the descriptor. See [New Class vs Classic Class](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass):

> New Style classes can use descriptors (including `__slots__`), and Old Style classes cannot.

You could either actually execute this on Python `3` and get it executing correctly, or, if you need a solution that behaves similarly in Python 2 and 3, inherit from `object` and make it into a New Style Class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    # body as is

obj = MyClass()
print(obj.age)   # 20
obj.age = 12
print(obj.age)   # 22
obj.age = 11
print(obj.age)   # 21
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like you are right. I have checked with python 3 and result as you discribed (something wrong with my preferences, i thought that i was usin python 3). But I have another question: In which case function:
{code}
property
    def age(self):
        return self.abc
{/code}
This function would be available ? Because it is shadowed be:
{code}
age.getter
    def age(self):
        return self.abc + 10
{/code}

Comment: @ДенисКотов If you use `age.getter` with `def age(self):..` you won't be able to use another function with the name `age`, this applies for both `Python 2` when you inherit from `object` and `Python 3` by default. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, that i asked. But i curious, why in this case we need age.getter decorator if we can use default one ?

Comment: Ah, take a look at this great answer for a good explanation on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554546/when-and-how-to-use-the-builtin-function-property-in-python

Comment: I mean that property
    def age(self):
        return self.abc is useless, because we have age.getter
    def age(self):
        return self.abc + 10. What is the reason ? We have lost method ... (

Comment: Oh I see now. Yes, you *don't* need `@age.getter` here since you've used `@property` with `def age`. You can remove `@age.getter` and do `return self.abc + 10` in `@property def age(self):..` and it wll work similarly @ДенисКотов

Comment: Using `@property` with a function after defines a `getter`. You then override this when you did `@age.getter`. You can chose either one of those and the functionality will stay the same.

Comment: @ Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard  But can i live both ? And how to call first one property def age(self): return self.abc, because if i do obj.age every time i call second ?

Comment: You can't have both, the second one overrides the first, you'll have to use one getter for the attribute @ДенисКотов