# Python @property vs @property.getter

Tags: python, properties, attributes

I'm writing a Python class, and it I'm using the `@property` decorator to create properties for the class.

I haven't found much in the documentation about this decorator, but from what I can gather from Stack Overflow and the instructions in my Python linter: in its entirety, a property created with the property decorator can take on the form *definition, getter, setter, deleter*, as shown here:

```
@property
def name(self):
    return self.__name

@name.getter
def name(self):
    return self.__name

@name.setter
def name(self, value):
    self.__name=value

@name.deleter
def name(self):
    del self.__name
```

I'm not entirely sure what the very first block is for. The code inside it is the exact same as the `getter` function.

What is the first block for; how is it different from the `getter` block, and if it is not, can I remove either one of them?

Comment: Where did you see that you need `@name.getter`? You most definitely don't need it, and it's also not covered in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)

Comment: The `getter` part is not required. The `@property` part acts as the getter.

Comment: @DeepSpace Like I said, I've just seen it around. VSCode gives me the options in the dropdown when I type `@name.`, and random questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729268/property-in-python-with-property-getter) have .getter in it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You code works the same, because the code for `@name.getter` is the same as the code for `@property`.

`@property` is necessary, because it defines the property.

If you try:

```
class MyClass:
    @name.getter
    def name(self):
        return self.__name
```

You will get error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/my/code/prop.py", line 1, in <module>
    class MyClass:
  File "/path/to/my/code/prop.py", line 3, in MyClass
    @name.getter
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

So, when creating a property, you always start with:

```
@property
def name(self):
    return self.__name
```

This creates the property `name` and also the `getter` for this property, which you can see here:

```
class MyClass:
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

print(MyClass.name)    # Note: we didn't create any objects
print(MyClass.name.getter)
```

The output will be:

```
<property object at 0x10beee050>
<built-in method getter of property object at 0x10beee050>
```

If you add `getter`, this will overwrite the original `getter`.

In your case, both getters were the same, so there was no changes. But try changing the code, making the new getter different:

```
class MyClass:
    @property
    def name(self):  # property and original getter
        print('This one will never get called')
        return self.__name 

    @name.getter
    def name(self):  # redefined getter
        return 'hello '+self.__name
```

Now the class has a new getter, and if you create an object `obj` and then use `obj.name`, the new `getter` will be called, and not the original one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough and well-formatted explanation!