# Questions about "yield from" and "next" behaviour

Tags: python

So I am making a generator from a list but would like to call next on it, which should just return the next item in the list, however it returns the same object, i.e. the whole piece of code is run again in stead of just returning the yield part. The example below shows the expected behaviour when looping through the list, but then the next returns 1 twice, whereas I would like the second call of next to return 2.

```
class demo:
    @property
    def mygen(self):
        a = [1,2,3,4,5]
        b = [6,7,8,9,10]
        yield from a
        yield from b

if __name__=='__main__':
    demo1 = demo()
    print([_ for _ in demo1.mygen])
    demo2 = demo()
    print(next(demo2.mygen))
    print(next(demo2.mygen))
```

There's a reason I am turning a list into a generator as it is the response from an api call and would like to dynamically return the next item in the list and make the api call if it comes to the end of that list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every call to the property creates a new generator. You should store the generator returned by the property to a variable. Then you will be able to call `next` multiple times. Change

```
print(next(demo2.mygen))
print(next(demo2.mygen))  # calls next on a fresh generator
```

to

```
gen = demo2.mygen
print(next(gen))
print(next(gen))  # calls next on the SAME generator
```

As others have pointed out, this behaviour should have you reconsider making this a property in the first place. Seeing

```
demo2.mygen()
```

makes it much more obvious that there is some dynamic stuff going on, while

```
demo2.mygen
```

gives the impression of a more static attribute producing the same object every time. You can find some more elaboration on that  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554546/when-and-how-to-use-the-builtin-function-property-in-python).

Comment: That's why it should not be a property, because if it's a function it makes you think what it does.